# create an 2D-array after starting the program C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I have two forms, where the first one is a start screen, where you have to write some variables in it and then you click next. The second form opens and i have handed over the variables and Now i want to generate an array which size depends on one of these variables. 
normally i write:

> int[,] daten = new int[160,160];

so i thought that the following works but it doesn't...

> int[,] daten = new int[V,V]; // where V is the variable

EDIT:
in my first form i have the following code:

> 

```
private void btnWeiter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (txbRohrdurchmesser.Text != "" && txbMesslanzen.Text != "")
             {
                 Form1 fu = new Form1(this);
                 fu.ShowDialog();               
             }
             else 
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus!");
             }
       }
```

and on the second form i have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        Startfenster fh;
        int Rohrdurchmesser, Messlanzen;
        int[,] daten = new int[160, 160];  // I want int[,] daten = new int[Rohrdurchmesser, Rohrdurchmesser];          

        public Form1(Startfenster aufrufer)
        {
            fh = aufrufer;
            InitializeComponent();                
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rohrdurchmesser = Convert.ToInt32(fh.Controls["txbRohrdurchmesser"].Text);
            Messlanzen = Convert.ToInt32(fh.Controls["txbMesslanzen"].Text);
        }
```

here is a picture of the error:
http://abload.de/image.php?img=fehlerg0ajv.png

Comment: If `V` is in scope and initialized I guarantee that works.

Comment: You need to tell us what error you're seeing.  "It doesn't work" is not an error message

Comment: @evanmcdonnal and the right type, and in the correct range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
    Startfenster fh;
    int Rohrdurchmesser, Messlanzen;
    int[,] daten; //Don't declare size yet

    public Form1(Startfenster aufrufer)
    {
        fh = aufrufer;
        InitializeComponent();                
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rohrdurchmesser = Convert.ToInt32(fh.Controls["txbRohrdurchmesser"].Text);
        Messlanzen = Convert.ToInt32(fh.Controls["txbMesslanzen"].Text);

        daten = new int[Rohrdurchmesser, Rohrdurchmesser]; //Define size here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, see that it works - then realize you either have a scoping issue or you're not casting the values from your Windows Forms to integers correctly.

```
int v = 160;
int[,] daten = new [v, v];
```

Windows Forms tend to return strings, which need to be converted to be used as an integer.

```
string val = myTextBox.Text;
int v = Convert.ToInt32(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

PhatWrat has it - here's some additional explanation:

The error message you should be seeing is:
"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Rohrdurchmesser'

Let's decode what it's saying:
The "field initializer" that it's referring to (the error message also give a line number) is

`int[,] daten = new int[Rohrdurchmesser, Rohrdurchmesser];`

The next part is "cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplications1.Form1.Rohrdurchmesser'.  That part is pretty straightforward.

The reason is twofold.
1st - Rohrdurchmesser is not initialized - it has no value yet - so how can you use its value to initialize a another field?
2nd - Even if Rohrdurchmesser was initialized, I don't believe that there's any guarantee about the order that fields are initialized, so you could still end up with an uninitialized variable trying to initialize another variable.

Rohrdurchmesser doesn't even get a value until much later when Form1_Load runs.

What you need to do is initialize daten in a method after Rohrdurchmesser is initialized - not with a field initializer.

Answer (score 0):

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        string x,y;
        int x1, y1;
        x=textBox1.Text;
        y=textBox2.Text;
        x1 = Convert.ToInt16(x);
        y1 = Convert.ToInt16(y);
        int[,] daten = new int[x1, y1];
```